# Node js: Assign mysql result to requests

Tags: mysql, node.js

Previously I was PHP developer so this question might be stupid to some of you.

I am using mysql with node js.

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM users where id="1"', function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
    req.body.currentuser = results;
  }
);
console.log(req.body.currentuser);
```

I tried to assign the result set **(results)** to a variable **(req.body.currentuser)** to use it outside the function, but it is not working.

Can you please let me know a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

The query call is asynchronous. Hence `selectCb` is executed at a later point than your `console.log` call. If you put the `console.log` call into `selectCb`, it'll work.

In general, you want to call everything that depends on the results of the query from the `selectCb` callback.  It's one of the basic architectural principles in Node.JS.

Comment: No but I need it outside the function. I just added the console.log for you guys to understand. But actually the client.query is written in a function and I need to return the values.

Comment: @Vasanth as said, you want to change your architecture so you don't need it outside the function. It's the way node.JS works.

Answer (score 1):

The `client.query` call, like nearly everything in node.js, is *asynchronous*. This means that the method just initiates a request, but execution continues. So when it gets to the console.log, nothing has been defined in `req.body.currentuser` yet.

You can see if you move the console log *inside* the callback, it will work:

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM users where id="1"', function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
    req.body.currentuser = results;
    console.log(req.body.currentuser);
});
```

So you need to structure your code around this requirement. Event-driven functional programming (which is what this is) can be difficult to wrap your head around at first. But once you get it, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No but I need it outside the function. I just added the console.log for you guys to understand. But actually the client.query is written in a function and I need to return the values.

Comment: @VasanthV, unfortunately there is *no way* to access it outside of the callback. It is a basic design principle of node.js. You *must* restructure your code around this.